# Linking tuleap artifact with git commit

Tags: git, tuleap

In Tuleap, the tasks have an artifact ID.
I want to link git commits to an artifact ID so I can see the commits linked in the "Cross Reference" frame of the task view.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just enter the artifact reference into your commit message, the commit will automatically become linked to that Tuleap artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text like,

`git #repo_name/commit-id-hex`

These can also be entered in the 'Cross Reference' after the fact.  This is useful for the case where code was committed before other tracker artifacts are created.  Ie, the commit message can not be re-written with the `short-id #artifact_id` in the commit message.

For example, a tracker with a short name 'bugs' and id 222. You would enter the text 'bugs #222' somewhere in the git commit message.  This is a preferred mode of working and is the easiest.  I prefer to put this in the title line, but it can go anywhere in a message.

However, if you create an artifact after the fact.  Given a repo named **program** with commit hash **24f2f74bbc8c1f77d05ca6c484e8525de76ddd77**.  You can enter `git #program/24f2f74bbc8c1f77d05ca6c484e8525de76ddd77` in the artifact comments to link the commit with the artifact (artifact is a bug, a requirement, a user story, etc).  **program** is the git name.  You can use `git remote -v` or use the web UI to find the repo name.  Usually, it is the same as the top git directory name, but it does not have to be depending on your workflow (how you clone/create the repo).

Comment: The general idea is very similar to Jira.  However, I include Tuleap specifics for modern 2023 versions.

Comment: If you navigate to the web commit details, it has a 'Reference' entry which is exactly the form you need to create the markdown link to the commit.